# Is there a way of animating a UITableViewCell so that the row flashes briefly to a selected state and then back to white on selection?

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uitableview

I just want the cell to briefly highlight either with a UIColor or a background image before animating back to the unselected state when a user taps the cell. I'm marking the cell with a star to show that it has been selected but would like the whole cell to highlight briefly just to show selection.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

add this line in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath -

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Comment: As easy as that! Thanks, do you know of a way to control the duration of the animation?

Comment: I dont think it is possible with this method. you can do it with custom animation of the cell.

Comment: If you want to control the animation because it takes too long, you may like how quickly it flashes when you set animated to false/NO

Answer (score 14):

I think the answer provided is solid if you want to animate just one row in response to selection.

I was looking for a way to do this with multiple rows simultaneously and without selecting and deselecting the rows in response to touch. I did the following:

Created a method in my UITableViewController called "calloutCells":

```
- (void)calloutCells:(NSArray*)indexPaths
{   
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 
                          delay:0.0 
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction 
                     animations:^void() {
                         for (NSIndexPath* indexPath in indexPaths)
                         {
                             [[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setHighlighted:YES animated:YES];
                         }
                      } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         for (NSIndexPath* indexPath in indexPaths)
                         {
                             [[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setHighlighted:NO animated:YES];
                         }
                      }];
}
```

Note that the duration and delay don't change the animation I've chosen since I'm using the built in animation on setHighlighted.

When I want to initiate the highlight/unhighlight animation from the UITableViewController, I can simultaneously highlight rows 3 and 4 of section 0 like this:

```
[self calloutCells:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0], 
                     [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0], nil]];
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Very simple, very elegant solution.

Comment: This works great, and has the added advantage of allowing programmatic flashing (`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is only called on rows that are actually tapped).

Answer (score 1):

swift3 version:

```
func calloutCell(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0,
                       delay: 0,
                       options: .allowUserInteraction,
                       animations: {
                        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
                        cell?.setHighlighted(true, animated: true)
        }) { (f: Bool) in
            let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
            cell?.setHighlighted(false, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Inside CEll:

```
self.selectionStyle = .blue
let uiview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 209, height: 251))
uiview.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
self.selectedBackgroundView = uiview
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more control over what the highlight looks like, you can use the "highlighted" property of the cell's label and set the selectedBackgroundView. Both will briefly flash on and off when selected

```
// text color
[[cell textLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[cell textLabel] setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

// background image
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-background.png"]];
[cell setBackgroundView:backgroundView];
[backgroundView release];
UIImageView *selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-background-highlighted.png"]];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundView];
[selectedBackgroundView release];
```